# How do I build subordinative clauses relating to genderless nouns?

Tags: grammar, gender

In German there are few nouns that have no article and thus seemingly no gender:

#### Examples

> [Google](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Google)
> [Nahost](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nahost)
> [Nord](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nord_Richtung_Lage_Norden)
> [Allerheiligen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Allerheiligen)

In the example "*Nord*" we could overcome this by using "*der Norden*" instead:

> Die Schiffe kamen alle aus dem Norden, der in Richtung ihrer Heimat liegt.

But how would I build this sentence using *"Nord"* or in case of any of the other examples:

> Die Schiffe kamen alle von Nord, *[der/die/das]* in Richtung ihrer Heimat liegt.
> Die Schuld liegt allein an Google, *[der/die/das]* die Suchergebnisse nicht korrekt filtert.
> Ich hörte nichts Gutes aus Nahost, *[der/die/das]* Heimat vieler Konflikte ist.
> Wir treffen uns immer zu Allerheiligen, *[der/die/das]* in Bayern ein Feiertag ist.

What grammar rules help me to build these relative clauses correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely treat these words as neutral when formulating clauses.
Therefore, it's **das** in all of Your examples.

This rule does not apply to names of persons. They are used without
article, but do have a gender:

> Hier kommt *[no article!]* Fred, **der** heute gut gelaunt aussieht.
>
> Das ist *[no article!]* Anna, **die** ihren Freund mitgebracht hat.

Esp. for company names, the issue is avoided in German by adding the legal form of the company:

> Das sind die Zahlen *der* BMW **AG**, **die** in diesem Jahr einen großen Erfolg hatte.

(AG = Aktiengesellschaft, feminin)

Comment: But even names of persons can be used with article, am I mistaken? See this question for example: ["ich bin die Gigili"](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/ich-bin-der-gigili)

Comment: You may use names with article in southern parts of Germany and in Austria (and in the TV-show "Sendung mit der Maus" ;), i.e. when talking to small children). However, You are always on the safe side if You don't use articles with persons' names.

Comment: @Black Your answer is exactly right. I would only add that using "wo" or "was" and the like to start the Nebensatz is another way around the problem. :-)