# Difference between "ihr" and "dessen"

Tags: pronoun, vocabulary, possessive-pronoun

If I want to say: “He is their son”, which is correct:

> 1. Er ist **ihr** Sohn.
> 2. Er ist **deren** Sohn.

What is the difference (if any) between *ihr* and *deren* in the meaning of *their?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Deren` or `dessen` are used to prevent misunderstanding concerning possessions in sentences with more than two persons or two groups of persons.

In your example it actually doesn't matter, but try to figure out who are the parents of the son in this sentence: `Sie haben ihre Freunde und ihren Sohn eingeladen`. The son could belong to family 1 or family 2. But using `Sie haben ihre Freunde und deren Sohn eingeladen` it's clear, the son belongs to their friends.

Comment: Actually, the sentence "Sie haben ihre Freunde und ihren Sohn eingeladen" is very clear. They invited their own son.

Comment: Maybe better: A speaks to B "Die Freunde und ihr Sohn kommen.". Which son will arrive? You can't hear if A says "Ihr" or "ihr". :)

Comment: So is this correct:*Meine Brüder können ihre Kollegen in deren Haus treffen.* I want to say that they are meeting in the colleagues' house.

Comment: @fluffy: you're right

Comment: Sometimes, the question appears if `deren` turns to `derem` in case of Dativ, but it does not.

Comment: How would you make it clear in English (`They invited their friends and their son.`)?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that *deren* here is a demonstrative (it can also be a relative pronoun), so this can be roughly compared to the difference between *them* and *of those* in English:

> Er ist ihr Sohn. – He is their son.
>   Er ist deren Sohn. – He is the son of those.

Therefore the usage of *deren* is unusual. Right now, I can think of only three reasons to use it:

- You are physically pointing at the parents (or something similar) while saying it.
- You are expressing disrespect of the parents (in which case you would most probably emphasise *deren*).
- The case explained in falkb’s answer.

Comment: I strongly suspect the second item on your list (disrespect) only works in English - I can't think of a single example where this would work in German. Also, in the first instance (pointing) it would still be much more common to use "ihr", wouldn't it?

Comment: I think that pointing at them does not influence the word-choice at all.

Comment: @Mac: It certainly is not as intense as in English, but just try to say a few sentences about, e.g., your neighbours refering to them once with normal pronouns (sie, ihnen, ihre) and once with demonstrative pronouns (die, denen, deren). But maybe this depends on the dialect or region (compare, e.g., to [using names with definite articles](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/ich-bin-der-gigili), especially the last example in Em1’s answer).

Comment: You're absolutely right about demonstrative pronouns in general, of course - but "deren" somehow still seems too formal/sophisticated for this usage. If I'm making a derogatory comment about my neighbours, I'll definitely rather say "Die Kinder von *denen* gehen mir aber mal richtig auf den Sack" instead of "*Deren* Kinder..." - but perhaps this is a regional thing, I don't know - what do the Northeners think?

Comment: To have `Er ist deren Sohn.` sound disrespectful you'd need to put emphasize on _deren_ for pronunciation.

Comment: @Mac: If you use sophisticated language all the time, you can also get disrespectful in it. However, given the fact that there are very few people who do and they most probably get disrespectful less often than average, you will not hear it that often.

Answer (score 0):

Genitive:   dessen (m) - deren (f) - dessen (n) - deren (pl)

Dative:     dem (m) - der (f) - dem (n) - denen  (pl)

Comment: I am sorry but I fail to see how this is relevant.