# Ist es unhöflich, Vornamen mit Artikel zu erwähnen?

Tags: article, person-names, politeness, spoken-language, address

Klingt es unhöflich die Vornamen, mit einem vorgestellten Artikeln zu sagen?

> z.B. Der Hans ist bei der Helga.

Comment: [possible duplicate:](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/ich-bin-der-gigili) even though the question in itself is different there might be an answer there

Comment: @Vogel612 Nein, die (Un)Höflichkeit wurde dort nicht diskutiert.

Comment: @Em1 ich habs mir auch nicht nochmal angeschaut. wusste nur noch, dass ich so ne ähnliche frage schon mal gesehen hab ;)

Comment: @c.p. It's somewhat impersonal, might be slightly unfriendly if intentionally distant but, generally speaking, it's just "normal", i.e. in every day speech it just happen to be like that; hence, there's no implication of unkindness.

Comment: Es ist regional sehr unterschiedlich. In manchen Gegenden ist es einfach normal; in Norddeutschland wird es teilweise als Beleidigung aufgefaßt ("so spricht man nur von Tieren").

Comment: Und in Kölle sagen sie sogar "Dat Helga..."

Comment: In Internetforen habe ich schon verschiedentlich erlebt wie Neulinge auftreten und sagen "Ich bin der Hans", so als ob es nur einen gäbe und jeder auf den Hans gewartet hätte. Etablierte User, die schon lange dabei sind, mögen vielleicht auch Hans heißen. Womöglich hat man sich längst drauf geeinigt wer der Hans ist, wer Hänschen, wer Hannes und wer Hans17 ist. Wenn aber derjenige weiß, dass er als Hans angekündigt wurde, dann kann sich mit dem speziellen Artikel so vorstellen und damit unterstreichen, dass er derjenige ist.

Comment: Wieso eigentlich nur Vornamen? Ist die Fragestellung bei "Der Herr Müller ist bei der Frau Meier." vs. "Herr Müller ist bei Frau Meier." nicht dieselbe?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Dem hätte ich irgendwie nie Unhöflichkeit attestieren können, diese Beispiele erwecken keinen Verdacht (liege ich falsch?). Denn ich sage auf meiner Sprache so, wobei Vorname+Artikel unhöflich ist und Artikel + Nachname ganz zu schweigen. In deinem Beispiel ist „Herr“ entscheidend.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since the link was broken, the new link to the results of the [Atlas zur Deutschen Alltäglichen Sprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/artikelvorname/), respective 9th round is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Schöne Antwort, der ich ein Plus gegeben habe, aber sie beantwortet nicht die Frage nach der Höflichkeit. „In der Schule“ garantiert keine höfliche Verwendung!

Answer (score 21):

In Süddeutschland ist das Benutzen von Artikeln mit Vornamen universell verbreitet und hat keine Konnotationen, die mir bekannt wären.

Comment: Das ist auch so in der Schweiz.

Comment: @Laurent: In der Schweiz ist die Benutzung von Namen mit Artikel altmodisch, wenn auch durchaus noch vorhanden.

Comment: @Quandary Innerhalb eines Satzes "Ich bi de..." muss aber doch der Artikel gesagt werden, wer das nicht will, kann zur Begrüßung bzw. Vorstellung im familiären oder freundschaftlichen Rahmen eigentlich nur den Namen allein sagen. Ansonsten bleiben die förmlichen Ausdrücke "Mein Name ist" etc.

Comment: @Martin Schwehla: Richtig, wobei es einen Unterschied gibt zwischen Dialekt und "regionaler Hochdeutschvariante/Hochdeutschverwendung".Wenn ich hochdeutsch spreche, sage ich: "ich bin Hans", und wenn ich Dialekt spreche, sage ich: "i bi de Hans".

Answer (score 10):

## Lange Antwort

Ich bin erstaunt über die Behauptung "der Didi" klinge distanzierter als "Didi". Ich kenne zwei sprachliche Paradigmen, von denen keines diese Deutung nahelegt!

Ich stamme aus dem Norden, lebe aber seit Jahren im Süden und in Österreich. Durch meine Erfahrungen im Süden,  habe ich gelernt dem Artikel vor Namen in der Umgangssprache keine Beachtung zu schenken. Anders gesagt:

> viele Muttersprachler verwenden umgangssprachlich immer den Artikel. Österreicher tun dies, wie ich kürzlich belehrt wurde, sogar schriftlich. In diesem sprachlichen Paradigma, bedeutet der Satz folglich dasselbe wie derjenige ohne Artikel, der jedoch ungewohnt klingt.

Was allerdings das Norddeutsche Sprachgefühl angeht, das ich in meiner Kindheit erwarb, so sah ich die Verwendung des Artikels als unerhörte Anbiederung. Danach wäre es unerhört jemanden so vorzustellen. Auch sich selbst.

> Meine Mutter (Norddeutsch) ereiferte sich regelmäßig darüber, wenn sich ihr jemand als "der Didi" vorstellt. Meine Großmutter ließ es im Norden niemandem durchgehen sie "die Mechthild" zu nennen. Es gölte ihr als tiefe Respektlosigkeit gegenüber einer alten Dame. In diesem sprachlichen Paradigma wird der Satz nicht akzeptiert. Müsste man ihn deuten, so würde man wohl eine sehr enge Beziehung zwischen allen beteiligten hineinlesen. Inklusive des Sprechers und des Rezipienten.

Ich will hier niemanden beleidigen, aber in diesem sprachlichen Paradigma könnte man auch denken es gehe um Tiere.

> Die Helga steht beim Hans im Stall.

Dazu habe ich gerade diesen [Beitrag von Bastian Sick](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-wenn-der-timo-mit-der-leonie-a-623493.html) gefunden, in dem er einen Leser zitiert:

> Wenn die Lotte und die Rosie Durchfall hatten, musste der Veterinär kommen, denn dann waren die Kühe krank.

Selbstverständlich gibt es auch im Norden die Möglichkeit, den Artikel betonend zu verwenden.

> Ich bin Hanno!
>
> **Der** Hanno? Der große Muffinbäcker?
>
> Ja, äh... Nein, ich meine...(wird puterrot).
>
> Willkommen, Hanno! Amanda, das ist Hanno. Der Hanno, den ich dir vorstellen wollte!

Dennoch vermute ich, daß das häufige Reisen und die Möglichkeit viele Sender zu hören die allerallermeisten Sprecher mit der Süddeutschen Variante vertraut gemacht haben.

### Kurze Antwort

> Ich würde trotzdem empfehlen im Norden gegenüber älteren Menschen den Artikel wegzulassen, da er sie tatsächlich beleidigen könnte. Gleiches gilt für das Sprechen über ältere Menschen.

Comment: Sehrt interessant zu lesen, dass die älteren Leute im Norden den Artikel hier als unhöflich empfinden. Mir geht es mit meinem süddeutschen Sprachgefühl genau umgekehrt. Wenngleich ich natürlich weiß, dass das im Norden nicht so gemeint ist, habe ich immer das Gefühl, dass der Name, wenn der Artikel wegfällt, nur noch eine Eigenschaft ist und nicht mehr die unmittelbare Beschreibung der Person. z.B. Ich bin Peter - Ich bin Bäcker. Mir fehlt in so einer Aussage jede Form von Selbstbewusstsein und wenn mich jemand ohne Artikel vorstellt, etc. finde ich dies zumindest irritierend.

Comment: @scienceponder interessant. Interessanter noch finde ich, daß sich der Artikel durchsetzt. Vergleicht man Altgriechisch (flexibel) und Neugriechisch (Artikel obligatorisch), stellt sich die Frage, ob diese Tendenz allgemeiner ist!

Comment: @scienceponder ich finde, dieser Vergleich spräche eher für die Norddeutsche Variante. Man sagt „ich bin Bäcker“, solange man nicht der bewußte/einzige/glorreiche Bäcker ist. Analog beim eigenen Vornamen.

Comment: Eben. Deswegen ist der Vorname mit Artikel viel Selbstbewusster! Ich bin DER Hans, und eben nicht irgendein Hans. Obwohl klar ist, dass es viele Hänse gibt.

Comment: @scienceponder finde ich nicht schlüssig, da es nicht so betont wird wie in dem von Ludi beschriebenen Fall. Sprich: die einzige Betonung die ich dem Artikel vorm Namen hier im süddeutschen Sprachraum entnehme, ist das Geschlecht des Sprechers, nicht dessen erhöhtes Selbstbewußtsein.

Answer (score 3):

Nein.

Ich finde, das ist gegenüber Dritten normal.
(Quelle: Ich bin Muttersprachler, Region: Rhein-Hessen)

Comment: Die Quellenangabe hilft hier nicht viel weiter. Muttersprachler _welcher regionalen Variante_?

Comment: Rhoihessisch^^ (Mainz)

Answer (score 3):

Nicht unhöflich, aber drückt mehr eine (oft in der Situation gewollte) Distanz aus. `Der Hans hat gesagt …` impliziert stärker, dass man nicht unbedingt mit ihm konform geht, als `Hans hat gesagt …`.

Ist so ähnlich wie `Der hat gesagt …` anstelle von `Er hat gesagt …`.

Nachtrag: Durch diverse Hinweise in den Kommentaren zeigt sich immer mehr, dass beim expliziten Hinzufügen des Artikels zum Namen die Wahrnehmung dieser Distanz im Süden des deutschsprachigen Raumes nicht mehr vorhanden ist.

Comment: Auch das ist allenfalls regional gültig. In anderen Gegenden würde man dem schon deshalb keine unterschiedliche Bedeutung zuschreiben, weil nur eine Version überhaupt in Gebrauch ist.

Comment: Kann ich mir gar nicht vorstellen, dass man andernorts den Unterschied nicht kennt. Dann kennst du wohl auch nicht den Spruch `'Die' ist Wagenschmiere!` wenn man jemanden dafür zurechtweist, nur den Artikel verwendet zu haben.

Comment: Kenne ich in der Tat nicht.

Comment: Meine Mutter (gebürtig aus Schlesien) sagte immer "'Der' steht im Stall -- und Du daneben!" :-) allerdings bezog sie sich auf "Der hat gesagt...", im Gegensatz zu "Der Hans hat gesagt".

Comment: Der Aussage von falkb muss ich heftig widersprechen (und damit chirlu zustimmen). Ich bin 1965 in Graz geboren und aufgewachsen und lebe seit 1997 in Wien. Die Version den Vornamen ohne Artikel zu verwenden kenne ich nur aus dem Fernsehen (in Österreich stehen ca. 10-mal mehr bundesdeutsche Fernsehsender zur Auswahl als österreichische). In der österreichischen Alltagssprache werden Vornamen ausnahmslos immer MIT Artikel verwendet, und dass obwohl die bundesdeutschen Medien seit Jahrzehnten das österreichische Deutsch zurück drängen. Und den Wagenschmieren-Spruch habe ich auch noch nie gehört.

Comment: Der Unterschied zwischen "Der hat gesagt" und "Er hat gesagt" wird aber in Österreich sehr wohl deutlich wahrgenommen. Nur spielen bei diesem Thema Vornamen gar keine Rolle.

Comment: Offensichtlich gibt es hier einen riesen Unterschied zwischen Süd und Nord. Ich hoffe, dass die Downvotes zurück genommen werden, wenn ich die Zeit finde, es diesbezüglich zu editieren. Danke für die Hinweise

Answer (score 2):

Jein.

In deinem erwähnten Beispiel macht es keinen Unterschied in der Höflichkeit.
Allerdings ist es gefühlsmäßig eher altmodisch, d. h., ich würde den Artikel einfach weglassen.

```
Hans ist bei Helga.
```

Allerdings drückt der Artikel eher eine subtile Ablehnung resp. Schuldzuweisung aus, z. B., wenn ich sage

```
Der Hans hat gesagt, dass "blablabla" …
```

dann impliziert das im Prinzip, dass `ich` als Sprecher/Schreiber damit nicht unbedingt einverstanden bin.

Wenn ich also anstelle von

```
Hans ist bei Helga.
```

sage

```
Der Hans ist bei der Helga.
```

dann drückt das eine gewisse Ablehnung/Unbehagen aus, resp. dass ich (als Sprecher) nicht damit einverstanden bin, dass Hans jetzt bei Helga ist.

Unfreundlich ist es in diesem Sinne allerdings nicht.

Comment: Ich erkenne da keine Ablehnung, die aus dem "der" kommt oder an dem "der" hängt/durch es vermittelt wird. Im Gegenteil; mir sind Leute begegnet, die sich selbst als "ich bin der Hoergen" vorgestellt haben. Das fand ich unhöflich, da es unterstellt, dass der Sprecher allgemein bekannt ist, eben der Hoergen, von dem man dauernd spricht. Natürlich hatte noch nie jemand von einem Hoergen gesprochen. Auch unterstellt es, dass es keinen zweiten gibt.

Comment: `Der Präsident des FC-Bayern hat gesagt ...` kann man sagen, aber wenn es zwei Ulis gibt kann man nicht sagen `Der Uli hat gesagt`, außer zuvor wurde bereits deutlich, von welchem die Rede ist.

Comment: @userunknown Hängt alles vom regionalen Usus ab … Wir haben drei Lauras und zwei Maxe in der fünften Klasse gehabt, und trotzdem hat immer »der Max die Laura gehänselt.«

Comment: @Jan: Ich würde sagen, dass das ein Unterschied zwischen Hochdeutsch und Mundart/Straßenjargon ist.

Answer (score 2):

In Österreich ist ein Artikel bei einem Vornamen Gang und Gebe und wird nicht im entferntesten Sinne als unhöflich empfunden. Ohne Artikel klingt es in unserem Dialekt gar komisch / unnatürlich.

Ich nehme als Beispiel mal den Hans - Helga Satz her zur Verdeutlichung der Thematik.

> Hans ist bei der Helga

ist bei uns im Dialekt

> Da Hans is bei da Helga [da ^= der]

Ohne Artikel klingt der Satz für uns unnatürlich, weil wir einen ortsbeschreibenden Satz bilden.

> Da Markus sitzt beim Fernseher.

Selbes Prinzip.

Meiner Meinung nach Bundesland / Land unterschiedlich. Sobald man sich gegenseitig dutzt, ist ein Artikel aber auf Höflichkeitsebene absolut irrelevant.

Comment: Willkommen. Stimmt. Danke für deinen Beitrag. Irrelevant ist der gebräuchliche Ausdruck.

Answer (score 2):

Nein, es ist nicht unhöflich einem Namen einen Artikel voranzustellen. Es ist aber grundsätzlich gesehen unhöflich, einen Nachnamen ohne Herr/Frau zu verwenden. Also:

> Der Hans (normal)
>
> Der Mayr (hmmmm … wenn man den Mayr siezt, dann nicht.)
>
> Der Herr Mayr (normal)

Und es ist anzumerken, dass Hans Mayr es nur unhöflich und respektlos finden kann, wenn er es mitbekommt. Wenn sich also zwei Studenten in der Mensa unterhalten und die besprochene Person nicht in der Nähe ist, darf ihnen auch ein *der Klüfers* statt *der Herr/Professor Klüfers* durchgehen.