# When is ‘er’ replaceable with ‘der’?

Tags: word-usage, pronoun, spoken-language, determiners

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Artikel anstelle von Personalpronomen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31956)*

Why is *der* used in the following example sentences (from online dictionaries) in place of simply *er*? Would these sentences still be correct, if *er* were used?

> Wo ist dein Bruder? — Der ist oben.
>   ⇒  Where’s your brother? — He’s upstairs.
>
> Wo ist der nur abgeblieben?
>   ⇒  Where’s he got to? [Where can he be?]
>
> Dein Vater, der ist nicht gekommen!
>   ⇒  Your father, he didn’t come!

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/why-is-there-a-definite-article-precedent-to-a-name http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15369/using-definite-article-with-peoples-names http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7269/ist-es-unh%c3%b6flich-vornamen-mit-artikel-zu-erw%c3%a4hnen

Comment: @Takkat Die Fragen sind aber nur peripher verwandt. Hier geht es doch gar nicht um Namen, sondern um Demonstrativpronomen.

Answer (score 8):

In your example sentences, the article "der" is used as a demonstrative pronoun and generally replaces "jener" or "dieser" when used that way (this is common speech). And yes, these sentences are still correct if you use "er".

Comment: And it might be worth mentioning that using a demonstrative pronoun for a person can be considered pejorative, especially in formal conversation and even more so when the person mentioned is present.

Comment: @tofro The example sentences could be found in actual spoken language and wouldn’t be considered pejorative at all (and defective neither). It couldn’t be replaced by _dieser_ or _jener_ without rephrasing, just _er_, which would be less emphatic.

Comment: Yes, not (very) pejorative but clearly only ok in spoken laguage. So, no, __not__ really _replacable_ at all..!

Comment: @Crissov Hmm. Try and say "Der da" to your boss in his presence and tell me how it worked out ;)