# Artikel anstelle von Personalpronomen

Tags: pronoun, style, determiners

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[When is ‘er’ replaceable with ‘der’?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29013)*

Ich höre manchmal, dass ein Artikel anstelle eines Personalpronomens benutzt wird.

> A: Hast du **Oliver** zum Essen eingeladen?
>   B: Ja, aber **der** kommt heute nicht.

Ist so eine Verwendung immer zulässig? Wenn nicht, worauf soll man achten?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29013/when-is-er-replaceable-with-der

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streng genommen handelt es sich in deinem zweiten Beispielsatz *nicht* um einen Artikel. Artikel stehen stets vor einem Nomen zu dem sie gehören. Dein erster Beispielsatz enthält einen mit einer Präposition verschmolzenen Artikel *(zum)* und könnte um einen Artikel erweitert werden – was vor Allem im Süden Deutschlands, in Österreich, der Schweiz, Liechtenstein und Südtirol üblich ist:

> Hast du **den** Oliver zum Essen eingeladen.

Dein zweiter Satz enthält kein Nomen, auf das sich der Artikel beziehen könnte. Stattdessen handelt es sich hier um ein *Demonstrativpronomen* – *Pronomen,* weil es **anstelle** eines Nomens steht. [Davon kennt das Deutsche einige](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Demonstr.html), am häufigsten sind für Nomen aber *der* (samt Beugungsformen) und *dieser* (samt Beugungsformen).

> Ja, aber **der** kommt heute nicht.
>   Ja, aber **dieser** kommt heute nicht.

Diese beiden Sätze sind grammatikalisch identisch. Der Erste ist eher umgangssprachlich und im Schriftlichen zu vermeiden. Der Zweite ist etwas förmlicher, aber ungewöhnlich; schriftlich würde man eher das einfache Pronomen *er* verwenden.

Answer (score 2):

Artikelwörter kann man als Artikel zusammen mit dem Nomen benutzen oder als Pronomen anstelle des Nomens.

Beachte: Der Gebrauch des bestimmten Artikels als Pronomen gilt als umgangssprachlich.

Das Demonstrativpronomen und der bestimmte Artikel haben als Artikelwort und als Pronomen die gleiche Form. Eine Ausnahme ist der bestimmte Artikel im Dativ Plural. Er lautet bei pronominalem Gebrauch denen.

[Die Info dazu](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/das-substantiv-nomen/artikelwoerter-als-pronomen/)