# Can we always use "Die" or "Sie" in the case of referring to 3rd person plural pronoun and even demonstrative pronoun?

Tags: article, personal-pronoun

Can we always use interchangeably "Die" or "Sie" in the case of referring to 3rd person plural either in written language and spoken language?

> Die haben einfach ihre Fotos auf das Auto geklebt.
>   Sie haben einfach ihre Fotos auf das Auto geklebt.

Comment: Please add 2-3 examples to make clear what you mean.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31956/artikel-anstelle-von-personalpronomen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Almost never. *Sie* is a personal pronoun, while *die* is either an article or a demonstrative pronoun. There are some simple cases where both a personal pronoun or a demonstrative pronoun can be used but there is a change in meaning:

> Sie stehen dort hinten.

They are standing over there.

> Die stehen dort hinten.

Those are standing over there.

Comment: Yes,  you're right like in English, but in spoken German I've heard a lot that people use "Die" while they indicate no specific people or objects as we use in demonstrative pronoun.

Comment: Oh, they do. It's just English isn't using a demonstrative pronoun when it should (^_^;). *How much are the apples?* – *They are one dollar a pound.* while German speakers say *Wieviel kosten die Äpfel?* – ***Die** kosten ein Euro das Pfund.* Because it's particular apples they are talking about.

Comment: @Armin and that use *may* be seen as dismissive or slightly derogatory whan talking about people. It's colloquial at best and *may* indicate lower social background. It's a fine line here that is hard to answer in a yes/no post w/o examples and w/o referring to social norms.

Comment: It's like pointing fingers. You shouldn't do it unless you really need to do. Also note *diese* oder *jene* is hardly ever used in speech because everyone thinks he/she points fingers at something or someone which is extremly frowned upon by Germans/Austrians/Swiss.

Comment: I got it! it's just colloquial use that makes it ambiguous. thank you all.