# "ihn" oder "den" um Substantiv nicht zu wiederholen?

Tags: noun, accusative, personal-pronoun

Um einen Substantiv nicht zu wiederholen was muss man benutzen, "ihn" oder "den"? Und wieso?
z.B.

> Da Sie den Vertrag unterzeichnen müssen, kann ich ihn Ihnen per Post schicken oder soll ich ihn Ihnen nächste Woche persönlich abgeben?

oder

> Da Sie den Vertrag unterzeichnen müssen, kann ich Ihnen den per Post schicken oder soll ich Ihnen den nächste Woche persönlich abgeben?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is ‘er’ replaceable with ‘der’?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29013/when-is-er-replaceable-with-der)

Answer (score 1):

Beide Varianten werden benutzt, wobei die zweite Variante nicht 100%ig korrekt ist. Dies merken aber nur wenige.

> Da Sie den Vertrag unterzeichnen müssen, kann ich Ihnen **diesen** per Post schicken oder soll ich Ihnen den nächste Woche persönlich abgeben?

Wenn man nun noch in beiden Varianten "abgeben" durch "vorbei bringen" ersetzt, stimmt auch die Aussage. Hier wird sonst das Angebot gemacht, den Vertrag im Namen des Empfängers an eine andere Stelle zu bringen.

Comment: Einspruch, soweit es die Pronomen angeht: Im täglichen Sprachgebrauch sagt niemand - jedenfalls in meiner Gegend, im 'Westen' - "ihn Ihnen", außer mit Bezug auf Personen, aber selbst da würde die vorbeigeschickte Person vorzugsweise nicht pronominalisiert. Der erste Satz ist eine Art "Kunstdeutsch", das niemand spricht, der zweite Satz ist völlig unauffälliges gesprochenes Deutsch, und die 'Verbesserung' mit 'ihnen diesen' ist wieder dieses Klimmzug-Deutsch. Der/die/das usw. zählen in dieser Verwendung als Demonstrativa, ich sehe sie eher als betonte Personalpronomen mit Bezug auf Sachen.

Comment: Es ist mir nicht klar, warum *den* bei der ersten Verwendung durch *diesen* ersetzt werden muss und bei der zweiten Verwendung als richtig erachtet wird.