# Warum gibt es keinen Artikel in »Heute ist Wahl«?

Tags: article, grammar-identification

Manchmal stoße ich auf solche Sätze und bis jetzt merke ich sie mir nur und mache weiter. Gibt es eine Regel, die besagt, wann kein Artikel vor Substantiven, zum Beispiel welchen die aus Verben abgeleitet sind, erforderlich ist?

Beispiel:

> Heute ist Wahl.

Comment: *bis jetzt merke ich nur den Satz und bewegen sich auf* – Ich verstehe nicht, was Du uns hiermit sagen möchtest.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Until now I just memorize the sentence and move on.

Comment: Ah. Du kannst *go on* nicht mit *sich aufbewegen* übersetzen. Meistens ist *weitermachen* eine gute Übersetzung. Siehe auch meine Korrektur Deines Posts.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Danke, Ich lese immer die Korrekturen

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Ehrlich gesagt finde ich auch *weitermachen* hier nicht sonderlich idiomatisch. Wenn man auf Deutsch überhaupt etwas in dieser Hinsicht sagen würde, dann vielleicht so was wie "kümmere mich aber nicht weiter darum."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solche Feinheiten des Ausdrucks sind oft nicht unbedingt logisch erklärbar. Es gibt ja so etwas  wie den Usus oder die Sprachpraxis, und manchmal reicht es, Dinge einfach hinzunehmen (and to go on).

Wenn man jedoch noch einer Logik hinter diesen Dingen sucht, dann vielleicht so:

Grundsätzlich kann man alle drei Sachen sagen: *Heute ist eine Wahl. Heute ist die Wahl. Heute ist Wahl.* Nur gehören die drei Sätze in drei verschiedene kommunikative Kontexte oder Lebenssituationen.

> Heute ist eine Wahl.

trägt mit sich, dass der Sprecher mit dieser Wahl nicht viel am Hut hat. Es ist für ihn "irgend eine" Wahl ohne weitere Bedeutung.

Zu den Wahlen, die wir in Deutschland so üblicherweise haben, hat der Normalbürger aber ein enges Verhältnis. Sie werden quasi als einmalige Ereignisse, fast als Persönlichkeiten wahrgenommen. Darum sagt man:

> Heute ist Wahl.

so ähnlich wie man sagt

> Heute kommt Kerstin.

(und nicht "eine Kerstin")

Dagegen würde man

> Heute ist die Wahl.

dann sagen, wenn es um Identifizierung eines Ereignisses in Abgrenzung zu einem anderen geht. Etwa so:

> Fritz: Hey, Max, wann war nochmals die Bundestagswahl und wann das Feuerwehrfest? Das war doch an zwei aufeinanderfolgenden Sonntagen.
>
> Max: Heute ist die Wahl, und nächsten Sonntag ist das Feuerwehrfest.

(Allerdings könnte Max auch sagen: "Heute ist Wahl und nächste Woche ist Feuerwehrfest". Das zeigt sein enges Verhältnis zu beidem.)

Hier gilt dann auch die Grundregel, dass bestimmter Artikel verwendet wird, wenn signalisiert werden soll, dass der Gegenstand, von dem gesprochen wird, in der Kommunikationssituation als bekannt vorausgesetzt wird.

Comment: "Warum gehst Du heute zur Versammlung?" - "Heute ist eine Wahl." Die Vermutung, dass das 'eine' eine Wurstigkeit transportiert, lässt sich m.E. nicht aufrechterhalten.

Comment: Das Thema Artikel vor Vornamen ist ein separates, siehe [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/7269/1696), und hat mit dieser Frage nichts zu tun.

Comment: "Heute ist Weihnachten." halte ich für eine naheliegendere Analogie als "Heute kommt Kerstin."

Comment: Oder „Heute ist Dienstag.“ Vielleicht ist „Wahl“ so sehr in unserem Bewusstsein verankert, dass der Tag der Wahl als etwas ewig Wiederkehrendes angesehen wird – wie Dienstage, Heiligabende, (schlechtes) Wetter…

Comment: "Die Wahl" meint eine spezielle Wahl, ist also ausdrücklicher. "Heute ist Wahl" beschreibt m.E. eher das Ereignis, als die spezielle Wahl zu betonen.

Answer (score 6):

Hier findet meiner Meinung nach der [Nullartikel](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Ohne.html) Anwendung, weil *Wahl* nur ein Abstraktum ist. In diesem speziellen Fall wird ja nicht einmal der Typ der Wahl angegeben, also *Bundestagswahl* oder *Kommunalwahl*.

canoo.net schreibt dazu:

> Abstrakta stehen ohne Artikel, wenn sie allgemein eine Eigenschaft, einen Zustand oder einen Vorgang bezeichnen.

Answer (score 2):

Eine wirklich knifflige Frage. Die für mich plausibelste Erklärung: Der Artikel wird weggelassen, weil die Wahl in diesem Satz weniger als ein Ereignis, sondern mehr als eine Art Zustand gesehen wird, ähnlich wie in:

> Es ist Sommer.

oder auch:

> Es ist Krieg.

Comment: Das erscheint einleuchtend, aber sagt man nicht auch: Heute ist Halloween / Heute ist erster Mai / Heute ist Nationalfeiertag etc.?

Comment: Man kann sagen "Heute ist die Wahl", wenn man eine bestimmte Wahl meint, auf die man sich ausdrücklich bezieht. Man kann aber nicht sagen "Es ist der Sommer".