# Ein Licht oder Licht? Sprichworten in Sätzen

Tags: grammaticality, article

Kann mir jemanden von euch erklären, wieso man hier keinen (z. B. unbestimmten) Artikel verwendet?

> Doch Ahrens sieht Licht am Ende des Tunnels.

Warum nicht *das Licht* oder *ein Licht*?

Comment: Warum sollte man - deiner Ansicht nach - hier einen unbestimmten Artikel verwenden?

Comment: Ähnliche [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/40150/1696).

Answer (score 4):

Es kommt in dieser Redewendung nicht darauf an, welche spezifische Lichtquelle zu sehen wäre, sondern eher auf das abstrakt Helle, das die Dunkelheit lindert. Ein Artikel, ob bestimmt oder nicht, würde eher Bezug nehmen auf eine spezifische Lichtquelle, was dann auch den metaphorischen Tunnel konkretisieren würde. Bei der Benutzung der Redewendung wird ja aber auf die Metapher gezielt, und da stört der Artikel durch die induzierte Konkretisierung eher.

Comment: Ich habe auch zuerst in diese Richtung gedacht, bin mir aber nicht sicher ob ich deine Meinung teile. Auch in der abstrakten Bedeutung "Helligkeit" kann und wird Licht oft zusammen mit einem Artikel verwendet.

Comment: Ich bin deiner Meinung. Jemand der *ein Licht am Ende des Tunnels* sieht, erwartet dort eine Person mit einer Lampe. Jemand der *Licht am Ende des Tunnels* sieht, hat Hoffnung, dass sich seine Lage verbessert. *Ein Licht* wäre hier wörtlich zu verstehen, während *Licht* (ohne Artikel) in dieser Wendung eine übertragene Bedeutung hat.

Comment: @jkalden Ich würde *Sprichwort* durch *Redewendung* ersetzen.

Comment: @guidot ich hab’s angepasst! Danke!

Answer (score 2):

Ich sehe es teilweise ähnlich.

Viele Substantive haben einen 'zählbaren' und einen 'nicht-zählbaren' Aspekt. [Die Bezeichnung *zählbar* ist üblich, aber verkürzt; gemeint ist: Ich kann ein Substantiv mit einer quantitativ bestimmten Menge benutzen (einen Kaffee trinken), oder die Menge unbestimmt lassen (Kaffee trinken, und keinen Kakao); sehr viele Substantive haben einen 'nicht-zählbaren' Plural (ich mag Schweine nicht), andere einen 'nicht zählbaren' Singular (ich mag Butter nicht), viele haben beides (gibt's heute schon wieder Schwein? = Schweinefleisch statt Rind)]

*Licht* kann, wie *Kaffee*, 'zählbar' und 'nicht-zählbar' benutzt werden:

> *In der Wohnung ist / brennt noch Licht*: nicht gezählt, in dieser Bedeutung auch nicht zählbar
>
> *Ein Rücklicht am Auto ist kaputt*: gezählt
>
> *Auf der anderen Talseite sieht man die vielen Lichter vom Martinszug*: nicht gezählt, aber prinzipiell zählbar.

Bei '*Licht am Ende des Tunnels*' ist das nicht-gezählte und auch nicht zählbare *(Überhaupt-)Licht* als Gegenbegriff zu *Dunkelheit* gemeint, nicht eine isolierte Lichtquelle, bei der man '*ein Licht*' sagen könnte. Wenn man irgendwo im Tunnel '*ein Licht*' sieht, ist nicht gesagt, dass man sich damit dem (und genau dem) Licht am Tunnelende nähert, es kann irgendeine Lampe unterwegs sein. Es könnte aber auch das langersehnte Tunnelende sein:

> *Ich sehe da hinten ein Licht, ob das wohl das Tunnelende ist?*

Zum bestimmten Artikel: Ich kann ebenso gut sagen:

> *Wir sehen endlich das Licht am Ende des Tunnels*

mit bestimmtem Artikel, hier ist '*am Ende des Tunnels*' Attribut zu '*Licht*', als auch

> *Wir sehen endlich Licht am Ende des Tunnels*

ohne Artikel, hier ist '*am Ende des Tunnels*' Ortsangabe.

Die Bedeutungen erscheinen mir leicht verschieden: Bei *das Licht am Ende des Tunnels sehen* ist (für mich) ein 'langersehntes' Licht assoziiert, ein konkretes Ziel, auf das schon lange hingearbeitet wurde. Ähnlich wären *die Durststrecke hat ein Ende* oder *endlich ist ein Ende abzusehen* zu verstehen. [Der bestimmte Artikel ist hier allerdings auch rein grammatikalisch erklärbar als 'attribut-induziert', vergleichbar mit dem *das* in '*das Paris des 20. Jahrhunderts*'.] Bei *Licht am Ende des Tunnels sehen* assoziiere ich eher eine mehr experimentelle Suche oder Erforschung mit unbestimmtem Ausgang und dem Risiko, nicht 'durchzukommen', ein zeitlich nicht erwartetes Hoffnungszeichen, den *Silberstreifen am Horizont*, ein Anzeichen dafür, dass sich die Mühen letztlich doch lohnen könnten.

Answer (score 1):

Ich hab keine Ahnung ob ich deine Frage richtig verstanden habe, aber ich hoffe dass dir folgendes hilft es ein bisschen besser zu verstehen.

Der Satz funktioniert im Deutschen ganz ähnlich wie im Englischen.

**I see a light at the end of the tunnel**

oder eben

**I see light at the end of the tunnel**

Die Bedeutung des Satzes ist eigentlich gleich, du kannst beides sagen.

(falls sich "I see light at the end of the tunnel" falsch anhört kannst du es mit "**there's light at the end of the tunnel**" oder "**there's a light at the end of the tunnel**" versuchen)

Zusammenfassend gesagt, kann man in dem Zusammenhang beides sagen.

Comment: Willkommen! Die Frage war auf deutsch, und da ist es hier üblich, auch auf Deutsch zu antworten. Es ist möglich, dass der OP Englisch nicht oder nicht besser als Deutsch versteht. In dem Falle wären auch die Vergleiche mit dem Englischen nicht hilfreich.

Comment: See [this meta question](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1048/43989) for full details about in which language you should  answer questions. Also, as a newcomer, I don't think there's any way you could be expected to know this kind of thing beforehand..

Comment: Thanks, i had no clue that i have to write it in german... thanks for the kind explaination tho :D