# How do you ask "who is this?" when someone knocks at your door in German?

Tags: expression, question

With no prior knowledge of this, I would say

> Wer ist das?

MY question is related to what I read here

http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasistas#Etimologia

It's a page from the Italian version of Wikipedia and it talks about the "vasistas", a name which is apparently used in Romance languages to identify the small opening in a door made to see who's knocking (by the way, I've never heard this noun).

The section on its etymology says that the term originates from German: when German soldiers heard some knocking at the door, they said "Was ist das?" and then French soldiers (who were knocking) identified the "vasistas" as the opening (I know, it sounds silly).

So I ask: is "was ist das?" a proper way to ask who is it at the door?

Comment: Oh, knock-knock jokes on GLU! :D http://witze.woxikon.de/klopf-klopf-witze

Comment: The story I've heard about _le vasistas_ is different: The French, who are accustomed to large windows that let as much light into the interior as is possible (hence the term "French windows" in the English language), were puzzled at the smallness of the windows in German houses, especially the tiny tilt-hinge window in the bathroom. Being polite, they asked the natives in the local language, "Was ist das?" The term stuck and when they returned to France, they experimented with tiny windows themselves. Instead of inventing a new French word for these portholes, they re-used ... _vasistas_.

Comment: Reminds me of _Fisimatenten_, supposedly from the French _Visitez ma tente!_.

Comment: German Wikipedia gives the [explanation I am familiar with](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4mpferfenster#Sonstiges): "Ende des 18. Jahrhunderts sahen deutsche Besucher in Frankreich das erste Mal Kämpferfenster und stellten dem Hausherrn diese Frage." More etymology [here](http://www.etymologie.info/~e/d_/de-ismen_.html#vasistas).

Comment: @EugeneSeidel Great, wikipedia may of course be wrong. Sorry for not having further researched the subject. Moreover, from your first comment I can get that the main answer is "Wer ist da?".

Comment: Dear Martina, if you click on the woxikon link I gave, you will find that the typical query is _Wer da?_ A more polite way of asking would be _Ja bitte?_

Comment: *Wer da?* is the short military (command) form of *Wer ist da?*. See also *Halt! Wer da?*...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual phrase is *Wer ist da?* (*Who's there?*). *Wer ist es?* is also possible, and *Wer da?*, though the latter sounds rather unfriendly. I can't imagine asking *Was ...?*, however.

A typical answer would be: *Ich bin's!* Really. :-) More useful is, of course, just giving the name. Or both: *Ich bin's, [(die)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3937) Johanna!*

As Eugene mentions, *Ja bitte?* is another possibility. However, it may already be understood as an invitation to enter. *Herein!* is the unambiguous phrase for that.

Comment: What does the _'s_ in _inch bin's_ stand for?

Comment: bin's = bin es.