# Using definite article with people's names

Tags: definite-article, person-names

So, in looking at some fairly basic German conversations, I came across the following:

> Hallo, wie heißt du?
>
> Ich heiße Susanne. Und du?
>
> Ich bin **der** Martin. Und wer ist das?
>
> Das ist meine Freundin, Anne.

In [another question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/why-is-there-a-definite-article-precedent-to-a-name), the accepted answer for such a use of the definite article precedent to a person's name is that this is a *"usage associated with the south of Germany more so than the north."*

That is fine, but what I don't seem to understand is why use it in this situation at all? I could get behind it if there were more than one Martin, and you were pointing out the Martin to whom you are referring, but in this case, the implication is that there is only one, so what is its usage here?

Comment: I took the liberty to slightly edit your questions. I personally very much dislike the name "forum" for this site, as well as "thread" for questions. Additionally you were talking about the "accepted" answer. If you disagree with the edits, feel free to roll back or call me out in [chat] or [meta] ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 I guess coming from a tech background and using StackOverflow extensively, I've transferred those terms. Apologies for causing any offence, it wasn't intentional.

Comment: lol offense? none taken ;) Additionally SO is the same. Not a forum, but a Q&A site. I try to keep these as separate as possible. The rules and mechanics are intrinsically different, and to prevent mixing stuff up I try to purge every reference to any se-site as "forum" or similar ;)

Comment: Well, what can we add?`It's very common in the South, and less so in the North. Why? Just because. It's language, not science.

Comment: Sure @Ingmar: the idiosyncrasies of language are but it's most defining feature, I guess.

Comment: People from Köln do it too, and Köln is not what I would call south

Comment: Let's call it an enclave, then :) Seriously, I can't speak in confidence for the North, or in fact anything but Austria.

Comment: @Ingmar... I'm not really sure how far north this actually goes. I'm from Berlin and for me it is utterly strange but I have a few friends from Köln who do it and my girlfriend does it, too. She's from around Bochum. I agree though about the very north... I don't think people from Hamburg would say that. Do you know how it is in Switzerland by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not asking where it’s commonly used – i.e. South and West, partially at least –, but why a **definite article before a given name** would be appropriate at all, be assured that this is the very reaction Northerners are likely to show when first encountering this peculiar phrasal structure.

After living more than seven years south of the Mittellandkanal and A2, i.e. in Aldi Süd country, I have stopped cringing every time I hear it, but I still hope to move away before my children adopt this. It sounds that wrong! 
As far as I remember, I was first exposed to this usage by the song [“*Ich bin der Martin, ne*” by comedian Diether Krebs](http://de.musicplayon.com/play?v=200443) in 1991, but back then considered it particular to the sociolect portrayed by his character, the eco-freak Martin.

I believe you can best explain it as an **emphasis marker**.

There are similar patterns that may be acceptable elsewhere, or are even more restricted geographically.

- *Wo ist die Oma / der Opa / die Mama / der Papa?* – quite common, though optional article
- *Wo ist der Meyer / die Müller?* – also optional usually, but less so for women interestingly
- *Wo ist der Huber Peter / die Schröder Helga?* – often considered exclusive to Bavarian
- *Wo ist der Schüler Heinz / die schöne Grete?* – article are mostly required with attributes (not just adjectives) before names of people

Comment: I cringe in the same way when I hear regional speakers in Britain refer to "our Lucy" or "our John".

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use it, but you need not do it. Other people may use it out of tradition or with special connotations.

For example, this can be used when talking to somebody as if he was a child.

> Das ist der Martin. Und das ist die Oma Gertrude. …

Answer (score 0):

I come from the northern half and say this too, and never noticed it was considered "wrong", until some people from even farther north thought it appropriate to correct me.

I believe the usage is from the influence of other languages, because the same usage of articles is very common also in italy, which apparantly is also southern neightbor to the german language area. Unfortunately I do not have knowledge in French, so I cannot decide whether this might be in roman languages in general.

Recently, while reading the books of the series "A Song of Ice and Fire" in english, I also found usages of articles in front of names where I would consider it wrong. So, apparantly it was used in more ancient formes of english, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an "answer", but something just occurred to me:

Being Bavarian and very much used to this construction, I feel weird saying "Ich bin Mac."

As a matter of fact, to me it makes my name sound like an adjective. Possibly (and I'd like to make it very clear that this is just a tentative theory), certain dialects developed the article + name combination as a marker?

Answer (score -1):

With the genitive case in danger of extinction, there is no longer the possibility to recognize from the name which case it is (genitive case would exhibit a trailing s or an apostrophe for names ending in s or similar, e. g. for Alex).

Note that in Goethes time the dative case still had such a suffix, where "Anne" would have become "Annen".

So in my opinion using the article may be an assimilation of the Englisch construction, to make the case visible, so "present a gift **to** Anne" would translate to "**der** Anne ein Geschenk überreichen"

Comment: So if you were introducing yourself, would you use the article in this manner?

Comment: @Ryan Being from and living in South Germany, instinctively yes, nearly everybody ("immigrants" from the North excluded) does it here.

Comment: @guidot disagree. I do not, most people I know don't and I find it to have the air of childishness. Also being from and living in south Germany ...

Comment: @guidot Which is interesting given the makers of the textbook to which I refer have included it as an example. If that is the case, and it seems childish, then is the intention of the textbook writer to make foreigners sound idiotic? You have to wonder...

Comment: Genitive is not by any means in danger of extinction? What's your backup for that claim?

Comment: @Emanuel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Dativ_ist_dem_Genitiv_sein_Tod. Surely its use is decreasing, even if extinction may be somewhat exaggerated...

Comment: This is a comedy book and there is very little about Dative vs. Genitive in it. It has been very successful but the author often doesn't really know what he's talking about, nor does he put in any research... as I said, it's comedy and it should not be posted here as a reference. For a much more informed take, check out this: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/genitiv-deutsche-sprache.php

Comment: @Ryan Coming from western Germany I don't include the article when introducing myself. The only occasions I see this happen is when a group is introduced to a person and some personsn have a name that does not clearly outline their gender. `Alex``Rene``Robin``Elliot`...

Comment: In Stuttgart and the surrounding region (and likely all of Swabia) this is common use for introductions, as well as in general conversation i.e. Was macht der Hans?