# What does "eben" mean in "Und da weckt mich eben die Therese"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The question on *eben* that occurs toward the end of this excerpt from Der Verschollene by Kafka.

> »Wenn du mich früh wecken gehst, so mußt du über den Gang gehen, hier im Zimmer schläft ein Gast. Er ist todmüde.« Sie lächelte Karl zu, während sie dies sagte.
>        »Hast du verstanden?«
>        »Ja, Frau Oberköchin.«
>        »Also dann gute Nacht!«
>        »Gute Nacht wünsch ich.«
>        »Ich schlafe nämlich«, sagte die Oberköchin zur Erklärung, »seit einigen Jahren ungemein schlecht. Jetzt kann ich ja mit meiner Stellung zufrieden sein und brauche eigentlich keine Sorgen zu haben. Aber es müssen die Folgen meiner früheren Sorgen sein, die mir diese Schlaflosigkeit verursachen. Wenn ich um drei Uhr früh einschlafe, kann ich froh sein. Da ich aber schon um fünf, spätestens um halb sechs wieder auf dem Platze sein muß, muß ich mich wecken lassen, und zwar besonders vorsichtig, damit ich nicht noch nervöser werde, als ich es schon bin. Und da weckt mich **eben** die Therese. Aber jetzt wissen Sie wirklich schon alles, und ich komme gar nicht weg. Gute Nacht!« Und trotz ihrer Schwere huschte sie fast aus dem Zimmer.

**Question**

What does *eben* mean there? I have two guesses.

1. It means *very*, and so *eben die* means *the very*. The distinction is between the very Therese in question vs. any other Therese. (Therese there, whom we just spoke to, has the job.)
2. It means *only*. The distinction is between Therese vs. anybody else. (Therese is the only one who can do it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's neither of the two. The [particle *eben*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eben_genau_gerade) (see in particular meaning 1 there) is used here to put a little emphasis on the sentence and to mark it as a conclusion or summary of what has said before. You could think of it as "and so it is" or "that's why".

Comment: Thank you. Is the non-emphatic form of the sentence: (a) *Und da weckt mich Therese* or (b) *Und da weckt mich **die** Therese*. If (a), why does *eben* "drag in" ("travel together with") *die* when *eben* modifies the whole sentence and has no special connection to *Therese*? If (b), what is the contribution of *die*? (For example, does *die* identify the particular Therese we have seen?)

Comment: It is b), and _die_ is the definitive article used with _Therese_. See http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3937/why-is-there-a-definite-article-precedent-to-a-name for a further discussion of this phenomenon. If Kafka's story was set in Hamburg that cook might have rather said "Und da weckt mich eben Therese", which would correspond with a)

Comment: One meaning seems to be missing from Duden page: *just now*, which would apply in *Als ich eben aus der Stadt kam...*

Comment: @guidot In your case "eben" is an adverb, which has its own [entry](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eben_soeben_vorhin_schnell) in the Duden.